# Plot multiple graphs from igraph package in the same figure

Tags: r, igraph, gridextra

I try to plot multiple `igraph` graphs in one figure using the `gridExtra` package

```
require(igraph)
require(gridExtra)
er_graph <- erdos.renyi.game(100, 5/100)
coords<-layout.fruchterman.reingold(er_graph)
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(1, 2)))
plot(er_graph,layout=coords, vertex.label=NA, vertex.color='red',main='red graph')
plot(er_graph,layout=coords, vertex.label=NA, vertex.color='blue',main='blue graph')
```

but the result was two separate graphs instead of grid of two graphs.
Any idea how to plot multiple `igraph` graphs on the same figure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try,

```
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
plot(er_graph,layout=coords, vertex.label=NA, vertex.color='red',main='red graph')
plot(er_graph,layout=coords, vertex.label=NA, vertex.color='blue',main='blue graph')
```

You'll have to mess with the margins (par(mar=)) a bit so that the graphs takes up the whole space.